# Get the first value instead of an aggregate value in GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I'm using GROUP BY with aggregation functions to aggregate a table (grouping by multiple foreign keys, a value column, and a timestamp column that's rounded down to whole days).

But there is a column where I need to get the first row in the grouping, instead of an aggregate value. I've looked at FIRST_VALUE() but it's a window function, not an aggregation function.

In pseudo-code I'm looking to do this [FIRST() function doesn't exist]:

```
SELECT
    ForeignKey1
    ,ForeignKey2
    ,MIN(StartTime) AS StartTime
    ,Foo
    ,AVG(Bar) AS Bar
    ,FIRST(Baz) AS Baz
FROM 
    Qux
GROUP BY 
    ForeignKey1
    ,ForeignKey2
    ,Foo
    ,CONVERT(DATE, StartTime)
```

How do I get the first value instead of an aggregate value?

Comment: *Define* first. You've not given us any *criteria* by which we can state an *ordering*. Without an ordering, there is no first.

Comment: When you say you want the "first row in the grouping" what do you actually mean (as RDBMSs don't have a concept of order)?  Do you mean the smallest (MIN) value, the highest (MAX) value, or is this based on another column, e.g. a row number, or even based on a CLUSTERED INDEX?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever by 'first', I mean the value of Baz matching the earlierst StartTime for the rows in each group.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply row numbers in a CTE and then pull out the entire first row, no need for the separate `MIN` aggregate:

```
;With Ordered as (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
           PARTITION BY
             ForeignKey1
             ,ForeignKey2
             ,Foo
             ,CONVERT(DATE, StartTime)
           ORDER BY StartTime) as rn,
        AVG(Bar) OVER (
           PARTITION BY
             ForeignKey1
             ,ForeignKey2
             ,Foo
             ,CONVERT(DATE, StartTime)) as BarAvg
    FROM Qux
)
SELECT * from Ordered
WHERE rn = 1
```